# The panels on Rails splits and are not displaying correctly in html.erb

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, css-grid

I was trying to make a masonry layout page in Rails. The problem is that the show links or the descriptions split from the corresponding images, like it can see on the image. [image]

The content as you see is splitted from the corresponding images. How I can make them work.  I tryed to put `overflow: hidden;` in the css but it doesn't work;

The code  is here

```
<h1>      Experience</h1>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag('pins') %>
<div class="containero">
 <% @pins.each do |pin| %>

  <div>    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default"></div>
      <div class="panel-body"></div>
      <%= link_to image_tag(pin.image, width: 350), pin %> 
      <%= render pin %>    
        <%= link_to "Show this pin", pin %></br>
     <% end %>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The pin.css.scss looks like this

```
.containero {
columns: 350px;
//column-width: 300px;
//column-count: 3;


}

#pins {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {

  margin: 5px;
  width: 314px;
}

.box img {
  width: 100%;
}
 containero div {
overflow: hidden; 
 }
```

Thanks!